# How to run code through eval?

Tags: php

here is my code of for loop

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
?>
```

and i want to run this code using eval so how can i run this.
i had tried this

```
<?php
$var = ("for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo 'The number is: $x <br>';
  }");
  eval($var);
?>
```

i want to run this code for learn the eval function. I am trying this but didnot get any answer. Please suggest me your answers.
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of double quotes.  As double quoted strings go through an evaluation phase, your $x variables are being interpreted - much like in your original echo.

If you change it over to use single quotes it should work:

```
<?php
$var = ('for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo \'The number is: \'.$x.\' <br>\';
  }');
  eval($var);
?>
```

Which is the eval version of:

```
<?php
 for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
   {
   echo 'The number is: '.$x.' <br>';
   }
?>
```

On my console this prints:

```
C:\SO>php -v
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Mar  3 2010 20:47:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

C:\SO>php test.php
The number is: 0 <br>The number is: 1 <br>The number is: 2 <br>The number is: 3
<br>The number is: 4 <br>The number is: 5 <br>The number is: 6 <br>The number is
: 7 <br>The number is: 8 <br>The number is: 9 <br>The number is: 10 <br>
C:\SO>
```

Comment: Your prints this \'; }'); eval($var); ?> i want actual output

Comment: That's odd.  I've edited my answer to explicitly state what this outputs on my console window.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the double quotes to single quotes. By default, double quotes read the value of variables, so what you have actually written (assuming $x is not set) is not `for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)`, but `for (=0; <=10; ++)`, which won't work.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because in double-quoted strings [the variables are stil evaluated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). Your code should use simple-quotes in order to work :

```
<?php
$var = 'for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }';
  eval($var);
?>
```

Note that the inner string should still use double-quotes for the variable `$x`to be evaluated by `echo`.

Comment: when i am running this program in localhost It Prints "; }'; eval($var); ?>

Comment: Well I can only assume you did the copy and paste wrong, it's perfectly working on my computer and prints `The number is: 0 <br>The number is: 1 <br> [...]`